# Base58 encoding/decoding of addresses in Micheline

Tags: javascript, encoding

who know some javascript library for decoding optimized Micheline representation of an address value?

```
011cd5f135e80fd8ebb6e43335b24ca6116edeba6900 => KT1BDEn6wobs7tDReKkGheXAhoq278TGaNn5
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Optimized addresses are 22 bytes, which follows the following format:

- The first byte is a tag, either 00 for implicit (tz) or 01 for originated (KT)

If the first byte is 00 and we are working with an implicit (tz) address, then:

- The second byte describes the curve and therefore the prefix. This is either 00 (ed25519/tz1), 01 (secp256k1/tz2) or 02 (p256/tz3)
- The remaining 20 bytes is the address

If the first byte is 01 and we are working with an originated (KT) address, then:

- The next 20 bytes are the address
- The last byte is a 00 buffer (to pad the length to 22 bytes)

To convert the optimized form to an address, you can use eztz and do something like this:

```
function getAddressFromOptimized(hex){
  var address, prefix;
  if (hex.substring(0,2) == "00") {
    if (hex.substring(2,4) == "00") prefix = eztz.prefix.tz1;
    if (hex.substring(2,4) == "01") prefix = eztz.prefix.tz2;
    if (hex.substring(2,4) == "02") prefix = eztz.prefix.tz3;
    address = hex.substring(4,44);
  } else if (hex.substring(0,2) == "01"){
    prefix = eztz.prefix.KT;
    address = hex.substring(2,42);
  }
  return eztz.utility.b58cencode(eztz.utility.hex2buf(address), prefix);
}
console.log(getAddressFromOptimized("011cd5f135e80fd8ebb6e43335b24ca6116edeba6900"))
```

The format is documented here: http://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/api/p2p.html#contract-id-22-bytes-8-bit-tag

Answer (score 3):

I believe you should be able to make use of Stephen Andrews [eztz](https://github.com/TezTech/eztz) library to access various tools from a js environment

I would speculate the function is this [one](https://github.com/TezTech/eztz/blob/master/src/main.js#L66) where you use the [KT prefix](https://github.com/TezTech/eztz/blob/master/src/main.js#L18)

```
  b58cencode: function (payload, prefix) {
    const n = new Uint8Array(prefix.length + payload.length);
    n.set(prefix);
    n.set(payload, prefix.length);
    return library.bs58check.encode(new Buffer(n, 'hex'));
  }
```

Comment: Ezy thanks for answer, but i try 
eztz.utility.b58cencode('011cd5f135e80fd8ebb6e43335b24ca6116edeba6900',eztz.prefix.KT) and this will return me "8RYhTWyrcLNgHVTCLfb3KP9TzGRZzttWK7CUJyYNLSD9xjpwC918e3BfpYBpwPBTy5UCi" not  "KT1BDEn6wobs7tDReKkGheXAhoq278TGaNn5"

Comment: @МихаилМагомедов yea sorry there were extra steps involved prior to calling that function as stephen showed!